# croniter get the next execute time of cron expression unexpected

Tags: python

I want to get the next execution time of a cron expression in Python 3.8, this is my code:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
cron = croniter.croniter(source.cron, now)
next_date = cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
```

but when I execute this, the result makes me confusing, when I input `'0 0 1 * * *'`, the result is `2020-11-01 00:00:00`, next month?

the cron expression is next day, the result should be next day,  but the result is next month? am I missing something? what should I do to make it right?

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression is for the first day of the next month. The fields of the expression are:

min hours day-of-month month day-of-week year